# Combine two arrays based on a condition - php

Tags: php, arrays

I want to combine two arrays but the difficult is part is I must also combine two keys only when a condition is satisfied.

```
$array1 = array(
10 => array('name' => 'I am testing', 'id' => 1),
20 => array('name' => 'This is a sample', 'id' => 2),
30 => array('name' => 'I am using stackoverflow', 'id' => 3)

);

$array2 = array(
100 => array('name' => 'I am testing', 'id' => 7),
200 => array('name' => 'This is second array', 'id' => 8)
);

$expectedarray1 = array(
0 => array(10 => array('name' => 'I am testing', 'id' => 1) , 100 =>array('name' => 'I am testing', 'id' => 7)),
1 => array(20 => array('name' => 'This is a sample', 'id' => 2)),
2 => array(30 => array('name' => 'I am using stackoverflow', 'id' => 3)),
3 => array(200 => array('name' => 'This is second array', 'id' => 8)),
);
```

or

```
$expectedarray1 = array(

[0] => array(10 => array('name' => 'I am testing', 'id' => 1) , 100 array('name' => 'I am testing', 'id' => 7)),
);
```

Is this possible? I know I can loop through but I ahve huge array one is 500 and other is 400 so looking for a better solution.

Thanks in advance Guys.

Comment: What's the condition to merge?

Comment: Without knowing the condition this is poking around in the dark...

Comment: There has to be a loop involved to do this logic. If you search for a function to call, it would have a loop in it as well. Also your question is not clear, do you want to combine any array value with any other that matches? Or in sequential order?

Comment: The name in the both must match. Sorry about missing that

Comment: @CodeiSir Thanks for your update. Yes I understand the function call will have loop. Just want to know whether there is any other way using other functions along with loop. I don't want the site to load longer.

Comment: "Also your question is not clear, do you want to combine any array value with any other that matches? Or in sequential order?"